# Redux-toolkit with Module Federation

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

Trying to build up microfrontends with Webpack 5 Module Federation. Having an issues with fetching remote reducers from micro-app.
This is what I've tried, and it doesn't work.

```
const loadAppBReducers= import('app-b/reducers');

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
   

    ...(async () => (await loadAppBReducers).reducers)(),
  },
});
```

Comment: Are you sure this is officially supported? The docs mention different approaches when dealing with async reducers: https://redux.js.org/usage/code-splitting#defining-an-injectreducer-function I'd try to circumvent the problem by delaying the initialization of the entire store until `loadAppBReducers` has completed. This would probably extend to the entire react app (don't mount the app until all the data is there). That said, I don't have any experience with webpack 5 module federation.

Comment: Assuming that the code there is inside of an `async` function, in _theory_ that ought to work. What matters is that the slice reducer functions exist and are passed in at the time the `configureStore` call actually executes.  But beyond that, "it doesn't work" isn't a sufficient error report to actually have any idea what's going on here.

Comment: Did you end up figuring out a solution to this?

Comment: Also looking for a solution for this.